# Using enums with objects c#

Tags: c#, .net, oop, enums

Sorry i'm quite new at enums and i'm trying to implement it in a logical context. In my Employee class i've created some employee objects. I've also created an enum for the Employee objects assignment status. My aim is to create a list of employees and give each employee an assignment status and finally iterrate through a list printing out the employee data and the employee assignment status.

I'm wondering:

1 - Is this a good case to use enums?
2 - How can i assign each employee with an assignment status? For example, if i want Emp1 to have AssignmentStatus.Assigned how should i apply this syntax-wise?

```
 public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool IsCurrentlyEmployed { get; set; }


        enum AssignmentStatus
        {
            Assigned,
            Idle,
            Trainee,
            NotDefined
        }


        public Employee(int id, string firstName, string lastName, bool isCurrentlyEmployed)
        {
            Id = id;
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            IsCurrentlyEmployed = IsCurrentlyEmployed;

        }


        public Employee Employees()
        { 

            Employee Emp1 = new Employee(1, "John", "Smith", true);
            Employee Emp2 = new Employee(2, "Kevin", "Moore", true);
            Employee Emp3 = new Employee(3, "Eric", "Johnson", false);
            Employee Emp4 = new Employee(4, "Michell", "McDevour", true);
            Employee Emp5 = new Employee(5, "Henry", "Jones", true);
            Employee Emp6 = new Employee(6, "Sarah", "Holmes", true);





            List<Employee> listEmployees = new List<Employee>();


        }
```

Thnk you

Comment: Please post some code for us to review and show some more research.

Comment: My appologies, seem i didn't post the code.

Comment: You define an `enum` type, but you also have to actually use it. Add a property of type `AssignmentStatus`. BTW, in .NET it is acceptable to call that property AssignmentStatus as well.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten " acceptable to call that property AssignmentStatus as well" - But only possible if the enum is defined outside the class.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 - Is this a good case to use enums?

Sure

> 2 - How can i assign each employee with an assignment status?

You need to expose a public property of type `AssignmentStatus` or create a constructor to do this

For example:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool IsCurrentlyEmployed { get; set; }
    public AssignmentStatus Status { get; set; }

    enum AssignmentStatus
    {
        Assigned,
        Idle,
        Trainee,
        NotDefined
    }

    public Employee(int id, string firstName, string lastName, bool isCurrentlyEmployed, AssignmentStatus assignmentStatus)
    {
        Id = id;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        IsCurrentlyEmployed = IsCurrentlyEmployed;
        this.Status = assignmentStatus;
    }

    public List<Employee> Employees()
    {
        Employee Emp1 = new Employee(1, "John", "Smith", true, AssignmentStatus.Assigned);
        Employee Emp2 = new Employee(2, "Kevin", "Moore", true, AssignmentStatus.Assigned);
        Employee Emp3 = new Employee(3, "Eric", "Johnson", false, AssignmentStatus.Assigned);
        Employee Emp4 = new Employee(4, "Michell", "McDevour", true, AssignmentStatus.Assigned);
        Employee Emp5 = new Employee(5, "Henry", "Jones", true, AssignmentStatus.Assigned);
        Employee Emp6 = new Employee(6, "Sarah", "Holmes", true, AssignmentStatus.Assigned);

        List<Employee> listEmployees = new List<Employee>();

        listEmployees.Add(Emp1);
        listEmployees.Add(Emp2);
        listEmployees.Add(Emp3);
        listEmployees.Add(Emp4);
        listEmployees.Add(Emp5);
        listEmployees.Add(Emp6);

        return listEmployees;
    }
```

I fixed your `Employees()` method too. Though I would not recommend putting code like this in the `Employee` class as it doesn't make logical sense, why should an `Employee` maintain a list of `Employees`?

You could then set the status like so:

```
Employee e = new Employee(0, "", "", false, Employee.AssignmentStatus.Assigned);
```

Or

```
e.Status = Employee.AssignmentStatus.Assigned;
```

Comment: Right now the Employees() returns an empty list

Comment: @Pavenhimself Better than not even compiling as it previously did.

Comment: This sure makes it obvious, adding a property of type AssignmentStatus. Your right, the employee list should be placed elsewhere, i just wanted to make sure it works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, this is a good scenario to use Enums
2. You need a property for the Status to be able to set it for each employee

   public AssignmentStatus Status { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

I have tidied up the code for you and shown how to assign the assignment status.
You'll find comments in the code that explain a little further.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool IsCurrentlyEmployed { get; set; }
    public eAssignmentStatus AssignmentStatus { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the assignment status for the employee. Prefixed 'e' to denote it's an enum and avoid clashes with the property name.
    /// </summary>
    public enum eAssignmentStatus
    {
        NotDefined,
        Assigned,
        Idle,
        Trainee
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Main constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <param name="firstName"></param>
    /// <param name="lastName"></param>
    /// <param name="isCurrentlyEmployed"></param>
    public Employee(int id, string firstName, string lastName, bool isCurrentlyEmployed)
    {
        Id = id;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        IsCurrentlyEmployed = IsCurrentlyEmployed;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor overload with eAssignmentStatus parameter
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <param name="firstName"></param>
    /// <param name="lastName"></param>
    /// <param name="isCurrentlyEmployed"></param>
    /// <param name="assignmentStatus"></param>
    public Employee(int id, string firstName, string lastName, bool isCurrentlyEmployed, eAssignmentStatus assignmentStatus) 
        : this(id, firstName, lastName, isCurrentlyEmployed)
    {
        AssignmentStatus = assignmentStatus;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates some employee objects, however, I would recommend putting this method inside another 'Factory' class, as you'd have to create
    /// an instance of Employee in order to call "Employees()"
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Now returns a list as this is what your method name implies.</returns>
    public List<Employee> Employees()
    {
        Employee Emp1 = new Employee(1, "John", "Smith", true, eAssignmentStatus.Assigned);
        Employee Emp2 = new Employee(2, "Kevin", "Moore", true, eAssignmentStatus.Idle);
        Employee Emp3 = new Employee(3, "Eric", "Johnson", false, eAssignmentStatus.Trainee);
        Employee Emp4 = new Employee(4, "Michell", "McDevour", true);
        Employee Emp5 = new Employee(5, "Henry", "Jones", true);
        Employee Emp6 = new Employee(6, "Sarah", "Holmes", true);

        List<Employee> listEmployees = new List<Employee>();

        return listEmployees;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see i should have set the enum as public as you suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the enum

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool IsCurrentlyEmployed { get; set; }
    public AssignmentStatus EmployeeAssignmentStatus { get; set; }


    enum AssignmentStatus
    {
        Assigned,
        Idle,
        Trainee,
        NotDefined
    }


    public Employee(int id, string firstName, string lastName, bool isCurrentlyEmployed, AssignmentStatus status)
    {
        Id = id;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        IsCurrentlyEmployed = IsCurrentlyEmployed;
        EmployeeAssignmentStatus = status;
    }


    public List<Employee> Employees()
    { 

        Employee Emp1 = new Employee(1, "John", "Smith", true, AssignmentStatus.Assigned );
        Employee Emp2 = new Employee(2, "Kevin", "Moore", true, AssignmentStatus.Idle );
        Employee Emp3 = new Employee(3, "Eric", "Johnson", false, AssignmentStatus.Trainee);
        Employee Emp4 = new Employee(4, "Michell", "McDevour", true, AssignmentStatus.NotDefined);
        Employee Emp5 = new Employee(5, "Henry", "Jones", true, AssignmentStatus.NotDefined);
        Employee Emp6 = new Employee(6, "Sarah", "Holmes", true, AssignmentStatus.NotDefined));

        List<Employee> listEmployees = new List<Employee>();

        listEmployees.add(Emp1);
        listEmployees.add(Emp2);
        listEmployees.add(Emp3);
        listEmployees.add(Emp4);
        listEmployees.add(Emp5);
        listEmployees.add(Emp6);

        return listEmployees;

    }
```